# undefined value in a fits header

Tags: python, undefined, header-files, astropy

Thanks for taking time to help me! Below is the issue that I am facing. Let's say I am reading the header of a fits image. One of the header cards is undefined object and I don't know how to handle this.

```
 from astropy.io import fits as pf

 hdu = pf.open('myfitsfile')
 hdu.info()
 img_hd= hdu[0].header
 print(img_hd['IMAGEZPT'])
 <astropy.io.fits.card.Undefined object at 0x109b35a20>
```

I am running my code iteratively over thousands of images and almost all of them have some values for it. e.g.

```
 hdu_base = pf.open(a_lof[38])
 img_hd= hdu_base[0].header
 print(img_hd['IMAGEZPT'])
 23.61687
```

I just want to assign some other values to this and continue. So, I tried

```
if img_hd['IMAGEZPT'] == None:
    img_hd['IMAGEZPT'] = base_ZPT #some value I know
    print(img_hd['IMAGEZPT'])
```

But as expected this didn't work since the keyword is not defined. So '== None' cannot work. The keyword exists, it is undefined though.

Any help will be appreciated!
Best,
Abhi

Comment: Hmm, having `UNDEFINED` come up in a header is unusual since it's mostly an implementation detail.  That sounds like a bug in Astropy.  Can you post a sample of your header?

Comment: The data I am using is public. You can take a look at the fits file. Go to IRSA-PTF image service (http://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/applications/ptf/). Then search using Field ID and CCD ID for single exposure images. Field ID= 100025, CCDID = 1. Let this query run and when its done, look for image with EXPID =49679 (it's 8th from bottom on first page itself). This is one of the few files which will return this message when you try to read the SEEING and IMAGEZPT keywords in the header.

Comment: The header seems to big to copy paste here.

Comment: Just an example, such as of the relevant keywords, would suffice

Comment: ('SIMPLE', True, 'Fits standard')
('BITPIX', -32, 'FOUR-BYTE SINGLE PRECISION FLOATING POINT')
('NAXIS', 2, 'STANDARD FITS FORMAT')
('NAXIS1', 2048, 'STANDARD FITS FORMAT')
('NAXIS2', 4096, 'STANDARD FITS FORMAT')
('ORIGIN', 'Palomar Transient Factory', 'Origin of these image data')
('CREATOR', 'Infrared Processing and Analysis Center', 'Creator of this FITS file')
('TELESCOP', 'P48', 'Name of telescope')
('INSTRUME', 'PTF/MOSAIC', 'Instrument name')
('OBSERVER', 'KulkarniPTF', 'Observer name and project')
('CCDID', '0', 'CCD number (0..11)')

Comment: I meant like the raw header data.  Like output from `head -c 2880 <filename>.fits`, which would output the first header block.  If it's been processed through the library already that doesn't tell anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If header is Undefined by AstroPy**

Import **Undefined** class from astropy

```
from astropy.io.fits.card import Undefined, UNDEFINED
```

And compare like this

```
if isinstance(img_hd['IMAGEZPT'], Undefined):
```

It compare the type of the instance of img_hd['IMAGEZPT'] with the Undefined type.

or like that

```
if img_hd['IMAGEZPT'] == UNDEFINED:
```

The second option should be more efficient because it compare the value of img_hd['IMAGEZPT'] instead of the type of the instance.

---

**If the header card is not present in the HDU Table**

Just replace

```
if img_hd['IMAGEZPT'] == None:
```

by

```
if 'IMAGEZPT' not in img_hd:
```

The **in** keyword check if the entry 'IMAGEZPT' exist in the hashtable img_hd.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Tried, not working. I think it would have worked if the keyword 'IMAGEZPT' didn't exist (just a guess). The keyword is defined, its value isn't.

Comment: Ok, I read wrong ! What did you think of the solution I propose on my EDIT ?

Comment: Thanks again! tried, not working                                                                       
    hdu = pf.open(a_lof[39])
    img_hd= hdu_base[0].header
    print(img_hd['IMAGEZPT'])

    if img_hd['IMAGEZPT'] is Undefined:
        img_hd['IMAGEZPT'] = 22
        print(img_hd['IMAGEZPT'])

Comment: I made a last edit, I think it could be work ! :-) (or not ...) I'm waiting for your return before improving my answer

Comment: This is working! Thanks a lot, Sir!!!!!!!! :-) "if isinstance(img_hd['IMAGEZPT'], Undefined):"

Comment: Nice ! And what about an == comparison with UNDEFINED ? (You should import UNDEFINED after Undefined). I can't test it

Comment: The code is running and it will be a while (~500 iterations before I would like to interrupt). I will test that and update you. Thanks  a lot!

Comment: Yes, that works as well ! Thanks a lot!      Abhi                                                                                 -if img_hd_base['IMAGEZPT'] == UNDEFINED:
    img_hd_base['IMAGEZPT'] = 22
    print(img_hd_base['IMAGEZPT'])                                                               - 22

Comment: Ok thanks ! The second solution should be more efficient

Comment: You should generally use `key not in value` rather than `not key in value`.  Also as I noted in my comment above (while it's great you were able to help) this seems to me like a bug in Astropy more than anything.  OP should not be getting `UNDEFINED` returned as a header value, generally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited my answer according to your advice. I find this weird too that a header is `UNDEFINED`.